# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION Read All on account

Tags: apex, permissions, permission-sets

While assigning permission to objects i am getting FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION,The user license doesn't allow the permission: Read All Account: []

What is this Read All and how to solve this error.

Comment: What permission were you assigning to what object? Some licenses don't let users do certain things ... like read all accounts.

Comment: I am assigning PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsCreate as True to all objects Child to Account.
I have seen View All and Modify All but what this Read All do and how to make is Read only?